# Spring MVC Java 415 Unsupported Media Type and path issue when posting data

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing a Spring MVC application that consumes a JSON web service. The application can save and retrieve data using a form (this is working and doesn't use the web service) but I'm trying to also perform this functionality by consuming a web service. I am using the RESTClient addon in Firefox to send and recieve data using my URIs.

Here is the relevant code:

GeneralIncidentWebServiceImpl.java:

```
//Omitted setter for generalIncidentService.


@Override
@POST
@Path("/addgeneralincident")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addGeneralIncident(GeneralIncident newGeneralIncident) {
   generalIncidentService.addGeneralIncident(newGeneralIncident); //This is not being hit when I try to add a new general incident

}

//This works in RESTClient
@Override
@GET
@Path("/getgeneralincident")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<GeneralIncident> getGeneralIncident() {
    return generalIncidentService.getGeneralIncident();
}
```

The data that I am trying to pass in is as follows:

```
   [
       {
           "lifeCycleStage": "NEW",
           "sourceType": "MYSOURCE",
           "createdTime": 1390522260000,
           "expiryTime": 1391040660000,
           "messageTitle": "test",
           "messageBody": "test",
           "furtherInformation": "test",
           "internalInformation": "test",
           "marketingInformation": "test",
           "className": "com.x.itds.domain.GeneralIncident",
           "incidentDetail": "GeneralIncident (incidentNumber:NO VALUE, tocCode: NO VALUE, version: 1)",
           "incidentClassName": "GeneralIncident"
       }
    ]
```

I am seeing two different problems:

**In the console:**

```
WARNING: No operation matching request path "/cxf/action/addgeneralincident" is found, Relative Path: /addgeneralincident, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: text/plain;charset=UTF-8, Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,.
```

**In the RESTClient Firefox addon:**

```
Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 24 Nov 2014 12:29:18 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I know from the console message (where it says: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;`) that I need to modify what the request should deem as acceptable content. I have seen examples that use the `@RequestMapping` annotation with the `headers` attribute set to the desired content type but these appear to be for controllers, and the above class I provided is not a controller class. I tried this anyway to see if it would work but it did not. Another thing to note is when I run my URI to add data, the relevant method is not being hit. I placed a breakpoint on the single statement in the method to observe what happens but it is not being reached.

Comment: Seems like you are not setting your content-type in the header while posting the request to the method...from messages it seems like application/xml request and your code expecting application/json

Comment: See my comment below to Tomas Smagurauskas's answer. I tried changing the content-type but got an error.

Comment: Not related to this error, but `addGeneralIncident` expects a single entity and you send an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are transferring correct HTTP header. In your case it should be:

```
Content-type:application/json
```

Because that what you defined your controller to accept. You also mentioned that you can't catch anything with breakpoint, that is because exception is beeing thrown in springs internal classes before your code is beeing reached.

Also, if you don't want to follow strict HTTP standards, don't define Consumes annotation, that would solve your problem in this case.

Comment: In RESTClient I added my own request to have a content-type of application/json and I got the following response: 

    `Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Mon, 24 Nov 2014 13:09:56 GMT
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1`

Comment: if it is throwing 500 that means your request is posted to the method,

Comment: Yes, then it means that it probably fails to deserialize your json or something similar.

Comment: The properties in the JSON object match the properties in the  GeneralIncident class. How can I map the data in the JSON object to the instance of GeneralIncident in the method signature? The properties in the JSON object are different data types.